# AngularJS checkbox checked custom value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to have a box checked by default with a custom value.

```
Are you ready? <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" ng-true-value="sure" ng-false-value="nope"><br/>
<tt> {{checked}}</tt><br/>
```

If I set it to that nothing displays until I click the box.  Is there a way to where it can be checked with a default value being something other than a boolean value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ng-true-value="sure"`. So, `ng-init="checked='sure'"`

Code Snippet

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked='sure'" ng-true-value="sure" ng-false-value="nope">
```

Plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/ejYSsyIjMZSZua9cQyv1?p=preview

Comment: Wow, I am greatly thankful for your answer.  Do you mind explaining why it requires the single quotes?  Thanks!

Comment: @Sethe23, angularjs will eval the ng-init expression. single quote is javascript syntax to assign value.

Comment: I didn't know that it would be evaluate it.  I should have tried that, but I couldn't find any documentation to convince me to try so.

Comment: @Sethe23, :). Welcome to angularjs. Refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit . Type for ngInit is expression. If type is expression, angular will eval.